# Searching partial strings PHP

Tags: php, search

How can you search a partial string when typing (not to use MySQL) like the LIKE function in MySQL but using PHP when searching a string, e.g.

```
<?php    

$string = "Stackoverflow";

$find = "overfl";

if($find == $string)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false
}

?>
```

But that will obviously work won't, but is there a function where you can search partially of a string? That would be great :)

**EDIT:**

What if it was in an array?

if i use the strpos, it does the echo, If I use it, it goes like truetruetruetruetrue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tend to use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$needle='appy';
$haystack='I\'m feeling flappy, and you?';

if(strpos($haystack,$needle)!==false){
   //then it was found
   }
```

If you want it to ignore case, use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

Note that a subtlety about this is that if the needle is at the very start of the haystack, in position 0, integer 0 is returned. This means you must compare to `false`, using strict comparison, or it can produce a false negative.

As noted in the manual, linked above

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on Booleans for more
>   information. Use the === operator for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

As far as using arrays, strpos is meant to take two strings. Using an array will produce `Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` or 1Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer`.

Okay, let's say you have an array of strings for which to search.

You can

```
$needles=array('hose','fribb','pancake');
$haystack='Where are those pancakes??';

foreach($needles as $ndl){
   if(strpos($haystack,$ndl)!==false){ echo "'$ndl': found<br>\n"; }
   else{ echo "'$ndl' : not found<br>\n"; }
}
```

Another way of searching for multiple strings in one string, without using an array... This only tells you whether at least one match was found.

```
$haystack='Where are those pancakes??';
$match=preg_match('#(hose|fribb|pancake)#',$haystack);
//$match is now int(1)
```

Or, use preg_match_all to see how many matches there are, total.

```
$all_matches=preg_match_all('#(hose|fribb|pancake)#',$haystack,$results);
//all_matches is int(2). Note you also have $results, which stores which needles matched.
```

In that, the search term is a regular expression. `()` groups the terms together, and `|` means 'or'. `#` denotes the beginning and end of the pattern.  Regexes can get pretty complicated quickly, but of course, they work! They are often avoided for performance reasons, but if you're testing multiple strings, this might be more efficient than they array looping method described above. I'm sure there are also other ways to do this.

Comment: Ok, good. But what if it was in an array? (check edited post).

Comment: Do you mean the haystack is an array? Or the needle? Check out the PHP docs - the first comment is currently 'strpos that accepts an array for $needle'

Comment: Essentially you'll have to use foreach to iterate over the array, whichever one it is. preg_match is a viable solution if you have many 'needles' and one 'haystack'.

Answer (score 3):

strstr() / stristr() (the latter being case-insensitive)

```
if(strstr($string,$find)!==false){
    //true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`strpos()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) can do that.

```
if(strpos($string, $find) !== false)
. . .
```

Note that it may return 0, so do use the type-equals operator.

Comment: When testing for existence, a strict comparison against false (`!== false`) should be used.

Comment: Yes, I edited while you were giving the downvote.  Give a guy a few seconds, ok?

Comment: I think the downvoter cast the vote before your edit. It's been revoked though apparently. No, I wasn't the one who downvoted :)