# How to check a particular part of url using php

Tags: php, url

I have a url in a variable.

```
<?php
$a='www.example.com';
?>
```

I have another variable, that has like this

```
<?php
$b='example.com';
?>
```

In what way I can check that $b and $a are same. I mean even if the url in $b is like

```
'example.com/test','example.com/test.html','www.example.com/example.html'
```

I need to check that $b is equal to $a in this case. If it is like `example.net/example.org` as the domain name changes, it should return false.
I checked with `strpos` and `strcmp`. But I didn't find it is the correct way to check in case of urls.What function can I use to check that $b in this case is similar to $a?

Comment: You can ignore the domain part and only verify the path because your server is configured to receive incoming request for that particular domain.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to compare the root domains in both `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: you need to use `parse_rul`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @AmalMurali You're right. I need to compare $b with $a. $a here is root domain. $b is url received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) for parsing the URL and get the root domain, like so:

- Add `http://` to the URL if not already exists
- Get the hostname part of the URL using `PHP_URL_HOST` constant
- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) the URL by a dot (`.`)
- Get the last two chunks of the array using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)
- Implode the result array to get the root domain

A little function I made (which is a modified version of my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678205/1438393)):

```
function getRootDomain($url) 
{
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }

    $domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
    return $domain;
}
```

Test cases:

```
$a = 'http://example.com';
$urls = array(
    'example.com/test',
    'example.com/test.html',
    'www.example.com/example.html',
    'example.net/foobar', 
    'example.org/bar'
    );

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if(getRootDomain($url) == getRootDomain($a)) {
        echo "Root domain is the same\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "Not same\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Root domain is the same
Root domain is the same
Root domain is the same
Not same
Not same
```

Note: This solution isn't foolproof and could fail for URLs like `example.co.uk` and you might want to additional checks to make sure that doesn't happen.

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51335)

Comment: As you said so, I am now stuck up with urls like example.co.uk. How further can we check in case of urls. Isn't there any restrictions for urls universally?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to do the heavy lifting and then split the hostname by the dot, checking if the last two elements are the same:

```
$url1 = parse_url($url1);
$url2 = parse_url($url2);

$host_parts1 = explode(".", $url1["host"]);
$host_parts2 = explode(".", $url2["host"]);

if ($host_parts1[count($host_parts1)-1] == $host_parts2[count($host_parts2)-1] &&
   ($host_parts1[count($host_parts1)-2] == $host_parts2[count($host_parts2)-2]) {
   echo "match";
} else {
   echo "no match";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this answer can help: [Searching partial strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276981/searching-partial-strings-php)

Since these URLs are just strings anyway

Comment: Read the question again. The OP is already aware or `strpos()`.

Comment: But the OP didn't think this was the correct way with URLs. But the URLs here are just strings. And therefore he can just as well use this.