# Php add nofollow to links if domains are in the array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace, domparser

How can i check if in the same string one or many from a list of domains stored in an array are present and link to them?

the array:

```
array  = ('example.com','domain.com','example.net')
```

and the text:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://example.net">dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing <a href="http://domain.com">elit</a>. 
Quisque quam urna, <a href="http://example.com/some-page/">hendrerit ut</a> vestibulum sit amet, elementum interdum dolor.
```

What i want to do is to add nofollow to the links if they are present in the array.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into using a DOM parser.  This would allow you to inspect all `<a>` tags and their href values, as well as to modify the elements themselves before output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with a regex. Use a DOM Parser instead.

```
function getRootDomain($url) 
{
    // @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068356/1438393
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
}

// your domains array
$domains = array('example.com','domain.com','example.net');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$dom->formatOutput = true; 

// loop through all links
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (in_array(getRootDomain($href), $domains)) {
        $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/69904)

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for your code, here is what i've done until now but is still not working... http://codepad.org/xSt3jpHs

Comment: @m3tsys: Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

i have an indirect solution to this. 
Use jquery and one external php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link=$("a").attr("href");
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                //data:"",
                url:"http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfile.php?link"+link,
                success: function(data){ 
                //get the response from the php file and add the nofollow tag if the response says so.

                }, //end of success
                error: function(){
                    //code if error
                    }// end of error
            });
</script>
```

and you php file would be:

```
<?php
$links_array = array('example.com','domain.com','example.net');
$link=$_GET['link'];
if (in_array($link, $links_array)) {
return true; //or something you can use
} else {
return false; //or something you can use
}
}
?>
```

that will handle it with no problem.